# Using PETSc to efficiently solve a small system sequentially?

Tags: fortran, sequential, petsc

I require solving a large set of (independent) *Ax*=*b* linear problems.
This cannot be parallelized (or more specifically, this is within each processor's responsibility anyway).

The *Ax*=*b* sets are small (say 10x10 at most) but are dense (Usually all terms are non-zero) and both A matrices and RHS vectors are completely different and independent.

What is the most efficient/practical way of solving a large set of small Ax=b problems using PETSc?

I.e. how costly would it be to have a single *A* matrix and a single *b* vector to be modified all the time and solved for each system?

Comment: Please ask one question per post and do not ask for software recommendations, they are off-topic.

Comment: solving small eigenvalue problems is I think done most efficiently with a direct diagonalization with a LAPACK routine (dggev for example)

Comment: @VladimirF - I asked regarding which linear solver within the PETSc package is the most recommended for a set of small problems (direct solver such as LU? iterative solver such as Conjugate-Gradient approach?)

FL.pf. I did not suggest these are eigenvalue problems.

Comment: You might be better of with the current question at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com but It is on-topic here as well, so it is your call. You can call a LAPACK solver as explained in https://lists.mcs.anl.gov/mailman/htdig/petsc-users/2014-December/023868.html  Which numerical method is the most efficient is really a topic for SciComp, not Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: Given your level of knowledge about PETSc, my suggestion is likely trivial, but regardless of that, for small problems, I simply use the Numerical Recipes in Fortran 90 by William Press et al. See chapter 2, for example.

Comment: @TheWhitestOfFangs well you didn't specifiy for what you want to solve your equations at all, so I took the for me most relevant problem. Doesn't really matter for what you want to solve though, there are LAPACK routines for everything. NumReps is a good source as well.

Answer (score 0):

After considering all the options, PETSc was not very efficient at handling the situation due to the need to rebuild/repopulate the matrices all the time with different values and ended up being relatively memory-costly.
I ended up putting PETSc aside for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since your A is small, why not try the direct method to solve it. SuperLU MT version or SuperLU serial version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the matrices at once, you can make a large, block diagonal matrix out of them and this will be efficient (vectorized and such).